# How can I use for loop to count numbers?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I need to count numbers upward and have it print out with a string "then" in between: 5 then 6 then 7 then... like this. I am very confused with using the parameters vs function name when you return. My code is below.. but could someone help with this?

```
function countUp(start) {
  start +=    
  for(var i = start; i < start + 10; i++) {
    console.log(start[i] + "then");
  }
  return start;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```
function countSheep(limit){
    for (var i = 1; i < limit; i +=1){
        console.log(i + " sheep")
    }
}

countSheep(10);
```

I used "sheep" instead of "then", but you get the idea. Since you just want to produce a side effect (print out a "1 then 2.." to the console, you don;t need to build up a string and then have your function return it.

If you did want to build up a string and then have your function return it though, you could do something like this instead:

```
function countSheep(limit){

    var allMySheep = "";

    for (var i = 1; i < limit; i +=1){
        allMySheep += (i + " sheep, ") 
    }

    return allMySheep;
}

console.log(countSheep(10));
```

Note: I started my loops at 1 (var i = 1) because I'm counting sheep, not numbers. You'd probably want to start yours at 0 (var i = 0).

Answer (score 0):

We can use JavaScript join function as well to achieve this 
Code

```
function getCountStr(count) {
    var str =[];
    for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        str.push(i);
    }
   console.log(str.join(' then '));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues with your code

```
function countUp(start) {
  start +=      // <<<<< what's this? It's an incomplete (and useless) statement
  for(var i = start; i < start + 10; i++) {
    console.log(start[i] + "then");
    //          ^^^^^^^^ why are doing this? you should only write i
  }
  return start; // you don't need to return anything
}
```

A cleaned and working version from your code

```
function countUp(start) {
  for(var i = start; i < start + 10; i++) {
    console.log(i + " then ");
  }
}
```

But this code will have an extra 'then' at the end like `1 then 2 then`, so here's a code that will handle this

```js
function countUp(start) {
  // a temporary array to store your numbers
  var tmpArr = [];
  for (var i = start; i < start + 10; i++) {
    // store the count into the array
    tmpArr.push(i);
  }
  // display the count by putting ' then ' between each number
  var stringToDisplay = tmpArr.join(' then ');
  console.log(stringToDisplay);
  document.write(stringToDisplay);
}

countUp(1);
```

Comment: Hi ShanShan, thanks for the input. What is the 'document.write(stringToDisplay)' for? Why would you use that instead of return?

Comment: It's just for this topic so you can use the "run code snippet" button and see the result. `stringToDisplay` is the final result, you can do what you want with it, return it or console.log/document.write it like I did (again, it's only for debug).