# how to classification json data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, classification

I want to do some classification from json data based by the data value.

I'm using some code that i get by another answer from stackvlow,
this is how i load the data :
[How to count JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640190/how-to-count-json-objects)
and this is the code that i use to do classification :
[How can I use for loop to count numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930916/how-can-i-use-for-loop-to-count-numbers)

Load the json,

```
const object1 = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "nitrogen_2019",
"crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
        "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
},
"features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "xcoord": 72,
            "ycoord": 92,
            "grid": 0,
            "n_mean": 2
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "xcoord": 72,
            "ycoord": 92,
            "grid": 1,
            "n_mean": 3
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "xcoord": 72,
            "ycoord": 92,
            "grid": 2,
            "n_mean": 4
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "xcoord": 72,
            "ycoord": 92,
            "grid": 13,
            "n_mean": 1
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
]};
```

This is the counting code,

```
function countbad(limit){
  var a = 0
  var b = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < limit; i +=1){
   if (Object.keys(object1.features[i].properties.n_mean) < 3){
     a = a + 1
   } else {
     b = b + 1
   }
}
console.log( a + " bad")
console.log( b + " good")}
countbad(Object.keys(object1.features).length);
```

But It gives me the incorrect results. Is there any problem with my code? is there any simple method to do classification data in json?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Please define "_code is not working_".

Comment: `but my code is not working` we guessed that much, because, if it working you wouldn't be asking :p

Comment: could it be the missing `,` after xcoord and ycoord properties?

Comment: oh sorry, the json is just an example. and yes the code is not run well

Comment: the expected value is "2 bad 2 good"

Comment: I'm attempted to ask something personal, but it's not OK with SO rules ... What do you mean when you say "_the code is not run well_"? It gives you incorrect results? It doesn't give any results? It throws an error? It throws stones to neighbours' windows?

Comment: sorry, im not to good in english. maybe the word " incorrect results" is the best word to explain my problem. thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly Your `JSON` is not valid as you are missing `commas` in the `feature > properties`.

Also If I correctly tried to understand your problem then I suggest you to use available `js` methods like `forEach` in this case.

```js
const object1 = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "nitrogen_2019",
"crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
        "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
},
"features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "xcoord": 72,
            "ycoord": 92,
            "grid": 0,
            "n_mean": 2
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "xcoord": 72,
            "ycoord": 92,
            "grid": 1,
            "n_mean": 3
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "xcoord": 72,
            "ycoord": 92,
            "grid": 2,
            "n_mean": 4
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "xcoord": 72,
            "ycoord": 92,
            "grid": 13,
            "n_mean": 1
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
]}

function countbad(){
  let a = 0
  let b = 0
  object1.features.forEach(e => {
    if(e.properties.n_mean < 3)
      a++
    else
      b++
  })

console.log( a + " bad")
console.log( b + " good")
}


countbad();
```

Comment: hehe i miss the "," because i delete the data before posting. thanks for the code

Answer (score 0):

```
function countbad(object1){
    var a = 0
    var b = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < limit; i +=1){
    if (object1.features[i].properties.n_mean) < 3){
            a = a + 1
        } else {
            b = b + 1
        }
    }
    console.log( a + " bad")
    console.log( b + " good")
}
countbad(object1);
```